# How to get up and running with webpack-serve?

Tags: webpack, webpack-serve

I am trying to use [webpack-serve](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-serve)(not dev-server) and I am a bit confused on how to actually run it.

I installed it, I have npm, webpack 4 and using VS Code with command line.

It seems to me I should just put "webpack-serve" and it should run but I just get

```
'webpack-serve' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Do I need to set some pathing or something along those lines?

Edit

I got it to "Build" by installing it globally.

I am now trying to get webpack-serve to function exactly like what I had when I was using webpack-serve but right now it is not(it does not open the browser, not sure how switch between dev mode and production mode and not sure how to get routing to work)

I have made an example here: https://github.com/chobo2/webpack-serve-example

Comment: have you installed it globally?

Comment: You mentioned you got it running by installing globally. So what is the issue now?

Comment: Yes, I got it to "build" but it does not work, I am trying to configure it to mirror what I had with webpack-dev-server

Comment: try running it from your node_modules folder like this node_modules/bin/webpack-serve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [NOT recommended](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/#global-installation) to install `webpack` or any `webpack` related tools globally so I'd recommend you uninstall all of them globally (NPM and Yarn) first..

I started a new project and created 3 `webpack` config files:

- `webpack.common.js`
- `webpack.dev.js`
- `webpack.prod.js`

In our `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "webpack-serve --config webpack.dev.js",
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
}
```

The thing I learned about `webpack-serve` is we have to define a `serve` object in our `webpack` config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // other configs ....
  serve: {
    // a minimal example 
    content: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  }
}
```

We will run our project by calling `package.json` scripts only,

e.g. `yarn run serve` or `yarn run build`

The full example is on [Github](https://github.com/bodazhao/webpack-4-react)

Comment: I am not using yarn, so I had to change it to "start"(as I don't know how to change the scrip flag anymore). Anyways I did get it to run! but when I try to build off your example like trying to add routing, hot realoading and even trying to get the browser to open. I get  options['add']  is an invalid additional property, where options["add"] could be any setting I try to add.

Comment: I also see you have stuff like webpack-command but I don't really know what they do.

Comment: Excellent, but webpack-command seems to be deprecated and we better stick to webpack-cli