# Webpack-Serve Example

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-serve

I'm in the nightmare process of updating one of my older projects from Webpack 3 to 4 and it's introducing a whole chain of things that need fixing. The most annoying one thus far is definitely switching from webpack-dev-server to webpack-serve due to it's lack of an actual example. So with that in mind, how the heck do I use it?

Using Webpack 4.14.0 and Webpack-Serve 1.0.4.

My webpack.config.js had the following options for webpack-dev-server:

```
devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: '/dist/'
}
```

I don't see options for history or public paths just yet, so I suppose I only need the content config option.

So according to the docs I'm supposed to do:

```
serve({
    content: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
});
```

But where do I put this? The Github README claims that the most commonly used is to put it `webpack.config.js` but that seems false because the example also does this:

```
const serve = require('webpack-serve');
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');

serve({ config });
```

Do I really import a config file into itself?

I'd appreciate an example. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to move away from the Webpack dev server? It should work as it did before Webpack 4 with the latest version.

Comment: The npm page for webpack-dev-server states that it is in maintenace-mode only, and that users should switch if they don't have to support older browsers. webpack-serve is also faster and additionally, I don't see any new documentation for how to use the required 'mode' webpack flag in webpack-dev-server.

webpack-dev-server was in fact working acceptably after going from WP 3 to 4, but I don't want to see warnings about the mode flag if I don't have to.

Comment: The documentation states that `Use webpack-serve for a fast alternative.`, not necessarily a replacement. It's in maintenance-mode only because all extra functionality you might want can be implemented as an express middleware.

Comment: Then can you indicate how I'm supposed to set the 'mode' flag in webpack-dev-server?

Comment: It might be that you have an old version installed. Try `npm i webpack-dev-server@latest`

Comment: I am running the latest of webpack-dev-server (3.1.4). Attempted using the --mode development flag but still getting warning.

Comment: Set `mode: 'development'` in your `webpack.config.js` in development mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130125/how-to-get-up-and-running-with-webpack-serve) very similar on "how to set up `webpack-serve`".

For simplicity, I also uploaded the full example to [Github](https://github.com/bodazhao/webpack-4-react)